# Cron job in unix

Tags: unix, cron

i have made a script `helloworld.sh` and its path is `/home/ehimkak/cronTabTest`:

```
#/usr/bin/sh
echo $1
if [[ $1 = "cron" ]] ; then
  echo "hiiiii"
else
  echo "sorry"
fi
```

If I run it from the `/` location with command

```
/home/ehimkak/cronTabTest/helloworld.sh cron
```

it runs fine.

---

Now I added a cron job by first setting the editor as vi (export EDITOR=vi) and then used command `crontab -e`.

There I added a line

```
10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /home/ehimkak/cronTabTest/helloworld.sh cron>>/home/ehimkak/cronTabTest/t1.txt
```

The result is that the script is running, but the output is not as desired.

The output in the t1.txt file I get is

```
cron
sorry
```

but my output must come

```
cron 
hiiii
```

There is no problem in the script, but i don't understand why `crontab` is behaving in such a way.
Please help...

Comment: Your echo statement was a good idea: more sure to be readable if you echo "\$i == '$i'".  If you're getting a blank line between sorrys then you know you're not supplying an argument.  Are you sure yuo don't have a newline after the script name and before "cron" etc..?

Comment: I tried to reformat your question. Please make yourself familiar with the [Markdown editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and check how I formatted your post.

Comment: i am sure that there is no blank line

Answer (score 2):

try to replace

```
if [[ $1 = "cron" ]] ; then
```

with

```
if [[ "$1" = "cron" ]] ; then
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the problem and the solution was very simple.

I just edited the shell line that is the first line
now the first line is

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
```

so I added ! and my problem was solved

Comment: It's worth noting that it ran from the command line because it was already in the bash environment

Answer (score 2):

something else for readability: instead of calling every 5minutes you can say it diffrent:

```
 bevore: 10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * "/home/ehimkak/cro...
 after:  */5 * * * *  "/home/ehimkak/cro...
```

*/5 will call the cronjob every 5th minute, that makes it more readable!
endo

Answer (score 1):

Form a typical crontab(5) manpage ....

The "sixth" field (the rest of the line) specifies the
command to be run. The entire command portion of the
line, up to a newline or % character, will be executed by
/bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL variable of
the cronfile. Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless
escaped with backslash (), will be changed into newline
characters, and all data after the first % will be sent to
the command as standard input.

i would give you two advices:

- first try to understand what is happening. Log is always your friend. Said that, in your script add something like:

  echo $# > /tmp/log

  echo $@ >> /tmp/log

  echo $* >> /tmp/log

And check if the parameters are being passed.

Another tip is try to pass everything escaped like:

```
10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * "/home/ehimkak/cronTabTest/helloworld.sh cron" >>/home/ehimkak/cronTabTest/t1.txt
```